# How to use liftDB function from the haskell package mongodb

Tags: mongodb, haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I am new to Haskell (so please be patient with me) and I am trying to write a simple program that uses MongoDB.

I had no problem with the [example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB-2.0.3/docs/Database-MongoDB.html) written in the documentation of the package.

Then I found in the documentation the function `liftDB` and I could not figure out how it works.

Here it is what I tried:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Database.MongoDB
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Reader

data MongoConfig = MongoConfig{ mContext :: MongoContext }
saveOnDB doc = do
    _ <- liftDB $ insert "myDocs" doc
    return ()

instance HasMongoContext MongoConfig where
    mongoContext config = mContext config

main = do
    saveOnDB []
    putStrLn "hello everybody"
```

This gives me the error:

```
No instance for (MonadReader env0 IO)
  arising from a use of `saveOnDB'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (MonadReader env0 IO)
In a stmt of a 'do' block: saveOnDB []
In the expression:
  do { saveOnDB [];
       putStrLn "hello everybody" }
In an equation for `main':
    main
      = do { saveOnDB [];
             putStrLn "hello everybody" }
```

I was't expecting it to work since I never provided the `MongoContext` but here are the problems:

- the data constructor for `MongoContext` is not exposed by the library, so I guess I am not supposed to create it directly.
- it looks to me that it expects to find the `MongoContext` in a `MonadReader` instance.

This is the type signature of the function:

```
saveOnDB :: (HasMongoContext env, MonadIO m, MonadReader env m) 
         => [Field] -> m ()
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Looks like you'd need to use the `access` function with a `Pipe` returned from `connect $ host "hostname"`, something like `pipe <- connection $ host "hostname"`; `access pipe master "dbName" (saveOnDB [])`.  I haven't ever used MongoDB or this library so I'm not 100% sure, but the types seem to line up, and it's strange to me to try to commit something to a database without having a connection open to it or telling it which database to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, you could do it that way. But it is really the function `liftDB` that I want to understand. All the relevant information about the database connection are stored in the MongoContext (which I did not construct in the example because I did not know how since the constructor is not exposed).

Comment: It is definitely true you aren't supposed to construct a `MongoContext` yourself, the constructor is not exported so that the library can ensure that all contexts are valid, much like how you can't access the constructor for `Data.Map.Map` or `Data.Sequence.Seq`, or any number of other types in `base`.  The `MonadReader` constraint comes from the `liftDB` function, which has the type `(MonadReader env m, HasMongoContext env, MonadIO m) => Action IO a -> m a`.  Since `IO` is an instance of `MonadIO`, that constraint is satisfied, but the `MonadReader env` constraint is not.

Comment: The `liftDB` function is written with this more general type signature so that if you were to use it with your own transformer stack, you could use it without having to `lift` the `liftDB`.  You only need that your monad has instances for `MonadIO` and `HasMongoContext env => MonadReader env`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your further comments below the question, you seem more interested in how to understand `liftDB`'s type and how to use it if you *had* a `MongoConfig` on hand, than how to *obtain* said `MongoConfig`, so let's look at that.

The type of `liftDB` is

```
liftDB :: (HasMongoContext env, MonadIO m, MonadReader env m) 
       => Action IO a -> m a
```

which means your `saveOnDB` function has the type

```
saveOnDB :: (HasMongoContext env, MonadIO m, MonadReader env m) 
         => Document -> m ()
```

The intuition behind this type is that `liftDB`/`saveOnDB` can run in any monad `m` as long as it provides you a way to do `IO` in `m` (the `MonadIO m` constraint) and also to access a `MongoContext` at any point (it is basically required to be passed around behind the scenes; this is what `MonadReader MongoContext m` means).

To make things somewhat nicer to use in case you already have some other data that you pass around anyway, you don't have to pass around explicitly a `MonadContext`; anything from which we can extract a `MonadContext` will do (this is the meaning of the `HasMongoContext env` constraint)

The problem you are seeing, then, is that you are trying to set `m ~ IO` (and, I guess, in your real app, `env ~ MongoConfig`), but there is no `MonadReader MongoConfig IO` instance.

The solution by now should be obvious: the `ReaderT` monad transformer "tunnels" the `MonadIO` instance of the underlying monad (so if `MonadIO m`, then `MonadIO (ReaderT env m)`, while providing access to some environment `env`. So if you choose `env ~ MongoConfig` and `m ~ ReaderT MongoConfig IO`, then you get something that will work exactly as intended.

In code terms, your `main` would look like this:

```
main = do
    ctx <- error "This is the part we don't care in this answer"
    let cfg = MongoConfig ctx
    flip runReaderT cfg $ saveOnDB []
    putStrLn "hello everybody"
```